# What statistical test solution should I use?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, confidence-interval

I tested an older software and I found one fault per 10 hours run/10 times run. New version of the software has created. How can I prove the software is operating correctly. How many test should I run? 
I used Poisson-distribution with 0.01 significance level for that and my solution is the following(1 fault per 10 hours):

1 − e^(−0.1*x) = 0.99
x = ~46 hours.

Comment: This question is completely unclear to me.  What do you even mean by "prove the software is operating correctly"?

Comment: How can I say the bug has been fixed? How many test I have to run for it to prove it is correct?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you mean "by one fault per 10 hours run/10 times run"?

Comment: Testing will never prove it is correct, unless you can test every possible input and every possible internal state of the computer.  Maybe the bug only appears once every thousand hours now.  Maybe once every million.  Maybe only when the date is February 29.

Comment: For example, I tested 50 hours and the fault appeared 5 times. Or I executed 50 test case on the sw and it appeared 10 times.

Comment: Of course, it is impossible, but I have to verificate the bug has fixed. What is a correct prove for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how much testing you do, you can never PROVE the bug has been fixed.

But if we assume that the number of appearances of the bug per time period has a Poisson distribution with a mean of $\lambda = 0.1$ per hour, then the probability of observing zero bugs in a run of length $t$ hours is $\exp (-0.1 \;t)$.  So, for example, if there is no change then the probability that you run for $46$ hours and do not observe the bug is $\exp(-0.1 \times 46) \approx 0.01$.